# UITableView does not appear in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have build `UItableView` with static `cells`, when I tried to run it nothing is appear in my simulator,

here is my interface builder looks like:

[image]
and here in simulator:

[image]

Comment: have you give delegate and datasource to UIViewController?

Comment: yes I have done this

Comment: have you use `objective-c` or swift?can you please show me your UITableView `Datasource` and `Delegate` methods.

Comment: I miss the return section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide return value for number of sections and number of rows. By default it is 0

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1   
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

       return 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the tableview doesn't have a programatic datasource connected to your view controller, with the numberOfCells/numberOfSections/cellForRow methods overriding the static cell population